# Tikz: \foreach and axis environment incompatibility

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I'm trying to plot a figure with TikZ. I have a few .txt files with the coordinates of the curves that I want to plot, in a list such as

```
file2.txt, 
file4.txt,
...
file30.txt
```

and I want to add them with `\plot` file in a axis environment. Also, I'd like to put them with different colors, creating a shading effects, let's say from blue to red.

In short, I want to create a sort of contour plot, but since I don't have the 3D function I have to import the coordinates.

I wrote this code, where I use two variables in `\foreach`, one for the file name, \x, and one for the shading of the color, \y, (see lines 'Original Idea'). It doesn't work because of some kind of trouble between \foreach and the axis environment.

I thought about other options, such as to explicate a relation between \x and \y (see code lines), use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` or an other trick with `\edef` but they doesn't work for different reasons:

- if I explicit the relation it seem like it doesn't want to calculate 3*\x (undefined control sequence)
- with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` it says 'illegal unit of measure'
- same for `\edef`

I read some topics on the use of `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and the trick with `\edef` but probably I haven't understood correctly how to use them in my code.

Can you give me a solution? Better it would be if you give me the corrections for all the 4 possible cases I proposed :-)

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfsys,pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \newcommand{\filename}{./figure/regionDep0/orthogonal}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, width=8cm, height=8cm]
        % Original idea: not working
        \foreach \x/\y in {2/0,4/7,...,30/98}
        {
            \plot[color=blue!\y!red] file {\filename \x.txt};
        }
%   
%       % substituting \y as function of \x: not working
%       \foreach \x in {2,4,...,30}
%       {
%           \plot[color=blue!3*\x!red] file {\filename \x.txt};
%       }
%       
%       % Trying with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach: not working
%       \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,4,...,30}
%       {
%       \plot [color=blue!3*#1!red] file {\filename #1.txt};
%       }
%
%       %   Trying with \edef\temp{...}: not working
%       \foreach \x/\y in {2/0,4/7,...,30/98}
%       {
%           \edef\temp{\noexpand\plot [color=blue!\y!red] file {\filename \x.txt};}
%           \temp
%       }       
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using an `axis` environment, which is provided by the PGFPlots package, you should use `\addplot` instead of `\plot`.

To use a different colour for each plot, one option might be using the `mesh` plot type together with `point meta=explicit` and `meta expr=\i`. This allows the use of colormaps instead of being limited to `colorA!<value>!colorB` expressions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  % Loads all required packages automatically
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.txt}
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 1
4 0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.txt}
0 1
1 3
2 5
3 3
4 1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file3.txt}
0 2
1 5
2 7
3 5
4 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \newcommand{\filename}{file}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap/bluered
        ]
        \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
        {
            \addplot +[thick, no markers, mesh, point meta=explicit] table [meta expr=\i] {\filename \i.txt};
        }   
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively (and probably better), you can use the `contour prepared` plot style if you put all contours into a single file. That way, you can even get labels on the contours (the labels can be adjusted or switched off, of course):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  % Loads all required packages automatically
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/relative round mode=fixed}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{contours.txt}
0 0 0
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 1 0
4 0 0

0 1 1
1 3 1
2 5 1
3 3 1
4 1 1

0 2 2
1 5 2
2 7 2
3 5 2
4 2 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \newcommand{\filename}{file}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot [contour prepared] table {contours.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you miss the point. The problem is to use two indexes to specify the file and the color, or one index to set both. If you use even \plot instead of \addplot without caring about the color it works. But with your version

`\addplot +[no markers] file {\filename \i.txt};`

the colours are set randomly without creating the shading.

Comment: @Nicola: Ah, yeah, sorry, I thought your main problem was getting the thing to run in principle since you were using the wrong syntax. I've edited my answer to show two different ways of achieving what I think you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks for the trick Jake. I still have a problem with your solution. If I plot more than 5 curves, some of them get dashed. Unfortunately I cannot post the whole code, I edit your code adding more `\begin{filecontents*} ... \end{filecontents*}` and I have the same problem, meaning that it is not a problem of the files. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Nicola: Yes, just remove the `+` before the `\addplot` (that way, the plot style cycle is not used).